# Can someone help me explain the nested for loop below?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the nested for loop. I cannot seem to understand why the 0 keeps getting printed to the next line.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()

{

    
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)

    {
    
        for (int k = i; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            printf("%d ", k);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }  
    


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should try stepping through this code with a debugger - that will likely give a much better explanation than we will be able to give in words.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger and trace the code line by line as it runs. Examine the program flow and value of the variables to understand what is happening. Or write it out line by line on a piece of paper.

Comment: @Uche "I cannot seem to understand why the 0 keeps getting printed to the next line." Maybe it is because  k can be equal to 0 after its decrement in the third expression of the loop for (int k = i; k >= 0; k--) when initially k was initialized by i equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put a bit more effort into your learning you could write:

```
int main(void)

{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        printf("outer(i = %d)\n\t", i);
        for (int k = i; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            printf("inner(i = %d, k = %d) ", i, k);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }  
}
```

```
outer(i = 0)
    inner(i = 0, k = 0) 
outer(i = 1)
    inner(i = 1, k = 1) inner(i = 1, k = 0)
```

I believe that explains everything.